# SQL Image DataType - C# Display Output

Tags: c#, sql, types

I have an image data type in my table. When I query using SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following in my results window, both grid and text.

0x255044462D312E320D0A0D0A332030206F[Truncated for Length]

I am attempting to replicate this in a little c# program.

However, when I use either SqlCommand or LINQ I get the output:
JVBERi0xLjINCg0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9FIDIxODgyDQovSCBbIDExNTAgMTUxIF0NCi9MIDIyM[TRUNCATED]

Any thoughts to what I need to do to get the 0x25... output to display? I have tried doing byte[] conversions and Encoding, but can't seem to find the right one.

If I am not clear, please let me know.

Edit:
I am not trying to display the image, just the 0x25...

Thoughts?

Comment: "JVBERi0xLjINCg0...." looks like encoded. What do you get when you print the byte array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string forDisplay = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(yourByteArray).Replace("-", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, .Net does not include any methods to print an arbitrary byte array as a single hex number.  (Until .Net 4.0's [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx))

However, you should be able to write

```
"0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "")
```

<strike>Note that this is incredibly inefficient; if you want to do this in real code, use a `StringBuilder` in a loop.
 **EDIT**:  Like this:</strike>

```
public static string ToHexString(this byte[] bytes) {
    var builder = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2 + 2);

    builder.Append("0x");

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("X2"));

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**: Here's a new version which really is faster.  (Yes, I know you don't need it; here it is anyway)

```
private static char ToHexDigit(int i) {
    if (i < 10) 
        return (char)(i + '0');
    return (char)(i - 10 + 'A');
}
public static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    var chars = new char[bytes.Length * 2 + 2];

    chars[0] = '0';
    chars[1] = 'x';

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
        chars[2 * i + 2] = ToHexDigit(bytes[i] / 16);
        chars[2 * i + 3] = ToHexDigit(bytes[i] % 16);
    }

    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for your response. this program will not go into production, so i don't have a worry for performance. I appreciate your responses!

Comment: @SLaks: I just ran some quick tests, and the `StringBuilder` loop appears to be 2 or 3 times *slower* than the "incredibly inefficient" `BitConverter`/`Replace`.

Comment: I cannot imagine why; I'll take a look.

Comment: I reproduced the slowness.  I suspect it's because of byte.ToString, which needs to parse its input & handle cultures, etc.  Here's a version which really is faster.

Comment: @SLaks: Yep, the new version is faster! This is pretty much what `BitConverter.ToString` does behind-the-scenes, but obviously you skip adding the hyphens which means that you don't then need the `Replace` call to remove them afterwards.